# Aptana 3 on Ubuntu 12.04 does not start

Tags: linux, aptana, ubuntu-12.04

I downloaded the latest Aptana studio on Ubuntu 12.04 and it does not start. When trying to start it from the command line it says:

> ./AptanaStudio3: kan een binair bestand niet uitvoeren. (dutch)

Which means "can't run binary file."

When running AptanaStudio3.sh it says:

> ./AptanaStudio3: Syntax error: "(" unexpected

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try to execute the 64bit edition on a 32bit os.
Use 'file AptanaStudio3' to check whether it is a 64bit edition.

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue with the incorrect build of Aptana Studio being uploaded for Linux (64-bit vs 32-bit). It has been corrected in the latest update.